# Simple PHP not displaying anything -Table generator

Tags: php, html

I've made a small PHP script to generate a table. I have gone over the cod multiple times and can't figure out why anything will not display. Any ideas?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title> Practice </title>
</head>

<body>
<table border="1">

<?php
$i=0;
while( $i < 20){
    if($i%10==0){
            echo "<tr>";
    }
echo "<td>".$i."</td>";
    i++;
    }
?>

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check the source of the page you are trying to generate. And check the error log.

Comment: replace your table with `Hi, world` and check it again. If worked, rollback and set a border to your table

Comment: `i++;` isn't going to work in php... `$i++;` will though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed a $ lol...

```
$i=0;
while( $i < 20){
   if($i%10==0){
      echo "<tr>";
   }
   echo "<td>".$i."</td>";
   $i++; // Right Here
}
```

Comment: Dang, apparently I needed to look it over 52 times instead of 51 lol. Thanks for the catch

Comment: It happens. You'd be amazed the things I've missed that other people catch. An extra pair of eyes always helps lol. Cheers!